# django rollback transaction in save method

Tags: python, django

I have the following piece of code overriding the save method of a model:

```
@transaction.commit_on_success
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):

    try:
        transaction.commit()
        self.qa.vote_down_count += 1
        self.qa.save()

        super(self.__class__, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    except:
        transaction.rollback()
        raise
    else:
        transaction.commit()
```

The expected behavior would be: self.qa attribute vote_down_count is incremented by one, but if any exception occurs in the super(self) save method the transaction rollbacks (that means the self.qa.vote_down_count += 1 is not committed in the database).

The actual behavior is: self.qa.vote_down_count += 1 is committed to database even if an IntegrityError exception raises from super(self) save.

Any thoughs?

Comment: Why are you committing first thing, then committing again at the end?

Comment: Commit first thing opens the transaction and ensure to commit everything that came before, doesn't it?

Comment: This is going to depend heavily on what database you're using. Postgres 8.0+ and Oracle support transactions properly. MySQL doesn't play terribly nicely with them, and most other databases don't support them at all. So question one is "does your DB actually even support transactions?"

Comment: @Gabriel, thanks for your reply. Yes it does support transactions, i have tested the same codes under Postgresql 8.4 and Sqlite 3.

Comment: Aside from stylistic questions on this function itself (i.e. ignoring the fact that there are better ways of writing it), why does the item get saved to the DB if super() fails?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Why not simply do:

```
@transaction.commit_manually
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    try:
        super(self.__class__, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
        self.qa.vote_down_count += 1
        self.qa.save()
    except:
        transaction.rollback()
        raise
    else:
        transaction.commit()
```

This is how [the docs](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/transactions/) imply to do it, though they say to do this in your view function, so you might not need the `@transaction.commit_manually` on the `save()` method, instead putting it on the view.

Comment: Change the orders of the operations doesn't solve the problem in my opinion, it doesn't prevent the error to happen, there are other cases when self.qa.save() must be done before. commit_amually decorator doesn't change the behavior.

Comment: I have issue like can you help me on that. You can Find my question on this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29574699/how-can-i-save-the-whole-db-transaction-if-there-is-no-error-in-python  @mike-desimone

Answer (score 3):

Try to use [savepoints](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/transactions/#savepoints). Something like this:

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):

try:
    sid = transaction.savepoint()
    self.qa.vote_down_count += 1
    self.qa.save()

    super(self.__class__, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

except:
    transaction.rollback(sid)
    raise
else:
    transaction.commit(sid)
```

Comment: I suppose you mean savepoint_rollback and savepoint_commit, it doesn't work either.

Answer (score 1):

I think Mike DeSimone's answer is the right one.

Concerning the database, depending on what MySQL version you use (if you use it), it might be that tables your database use MyISAM engine, that does not support transactions.

To check it just run in mysql shell:

```
SELECT TABLE_NAME, 
    ENGINE 
    FROM information_schema.TABLES 
    where TABLE_SCHEMA = 'your_db_name' ;
```

You can alter your tables to InnoDB and set default_storage_engine to innodb in MySQL config.
(Details here: http://parasjain.net/2010/06/08/how-to-switch-to-innodb-database-in-mysql/.

After that transactions should work. It is better to use Postgres, but if you want to use MySQL/InnoDB, then probably you'll need a workaround for loading fixtures with forward references (the BugFix is already present in Django Trunk, and I've also ported it to Django 1.3.1, see [Django 1.3.1.1 on Github](https://github.com/kipanshi/django/tree/1.3.1.1)).