# How can I save the whole DB transaction if there is no error in python

Tags: django, database, python-2.7, import, transactions

I have many files in a folder I am open the folder and import all the data inside all the files into my model, Here My program import data's in one file at a time,so it will read all data in the file once and I iterate through each line at the end of each line I save the transaction to database using `obj.save()`.

Here I am facing some exception while import may type mismatch error so the program stop import of that file and half of the data will be imported and it move to next file. So this problem cause duplicate data so here I need save the transaction using `obj.save()` of a file if there is no exception how can i achieve this can any one help me

```
        fromFile=open(path)
        for eachLine in fromFile:
            obj = SAMP()
            fieldsInline = eachLine.split(",")
            n=len(fieldsInline)
            if lines!=1:
            #obj.dates =  dates
                obj.col1 = fieldsInline[0].strip()
                obj.col2 = fieldsInline[1].strip()
                obj.col3 = fieldsInline[2].strip()
                obj.col4 = fieldsInline[3].strip()

                obj.save() 
            lines+=1

        except BaseException as e:
            logging.info('\tError in importing %s line %d : %s' % (path, lines, e.__str__()))
        else: 
            logging.info("\tImported %s, %d lines" % (path, lines))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a [transaction](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/transactions/).

So your function should become like this:

```
from django.db import transaction

@transaction.commit_on_success
def func():
    pass
```

or:

```
from django.db import transaction

def func():
    # Some code
    with transaction.commit_on_success():
        pass
```

> If the function returns successfully, then Django will commit all work done within the function at that point. If the function raises an exception, though, Django will roll back the transaction.

Comment: I tried this code but its not works for me it shows that some middle ware class are missing @Mohammad ali baghershe

Comment: @Krish Which version of django are you using?

Comment: djang1.6.5 python 2.7 @Mohammad ali baghershemirani

Comment: Bear in mind that transaction suport was significantly changed in Django 1.7.